# Cannot use pure virtual functions in my abstract class when using it in boost.python

Tags: python, c++, boost, polymorphism, boost-python

I'm trying to extend Python with my C++ library and I'm running into a few issues with this particular case: Let's say there is an abstract class called `Shape` now I want to allow Python to inherit from Shape and basically implement its own `Shape`, but also be able to use some existing implementations of Shape in the C++ code. Let me show some code:

```
class Shape {
public:
    virtual inline double get_area() const = 0;
};
```

Great, now let's say there is a C++ class called `Circle`.

```
class Circle : public Shape {
public:
    Circle() = default;
    inline double get_area() const override { return 0.5; }
}
```

Okay, let's write a wrapper for `Shape` (version 1):

```
struct ShapeWrap : public Shape, public wrapper<Shape>{
   inline double get_area() const override {
      if (auto py_func = this->get_override("get")) return py_func();
      return Shape::get_area();
   }
   inline double default_get_area() const {
      return this->Shape::get_area();
   }
};
```

and then define Shape this way:

```
class_<ShapeWrap, boost::noncopyable>("Shape")
        .def("get_area", &Shape::get_area, &ShapeWrap::default_get_area));
```

Okay, now this is a problem because `Shape` is an abstract class and rightfully so it doesn't implement `get_area` (it's pure virtual). Alright, how about we scratch all of this and write it this way?

```
struct ShapeWrap : public Shape, public wrapper<Shape>{
   inline double get_area() const override {
      if (auto py_func = this->get_override("get")) return py_func();
      return 0.0;
   }
};
```

and then define `Shape` like this:

```
class_<ShapeWrap, boost::noncopyable>("Shape")
        .def("get_area", pure_virtual(&ShapeWrap::get_area));
```

Okay, so that works perfectly fine for the objects that Python overrides. However, if I create a `Circle` object within Python, it would give me the following error:

```
Boost.Python.ArgumentError: Python argument types in
    Shape.get_area(Circle)
did not match C++ signature:
    get_area(ShapeWrap {lvalue})
    get_area(ShapeWrap {lvalue})
```

Now, all of this would be fixed IF I make `get_area` in the `Shape` class to return 0.0 as a default behavior but I don't want to write my API that way just to support Python, I'd like to have a default function for when the function isn't available and return 0.0 ONLY for Python because the notion of abstract classes doesn't exist in the same way in Python and that's fine but then I'll get to have `Shape` as an abstract class for the rest of my C++ API. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Look how `struct P` is dealt with in [this example](http://www.boost.org/libs/python/doc/html/reference/high_level_components/boost_python_wrapper_hpp.html#high_level_components.boost_python_wrapper_hpp.example) in the documentation. PS: it's also in [the tutorial](http://www.boost.org/libs/python/doc/html/tutorial/tutorial/exposing.html#tutorial.exposing.class_virtual_functions) but you may have missed it because it is confusingly near a  MSVC 6/7 workaround.

Comment: wow, you're totally right, my mistake is that I pass the wrappers function to the pure_virtual function. Works like a charm now. You should make that a response so I can mark it as an answer @llonesmiz

Comment: Please do so yourself and I will upvote it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @llonesmiz, I realized the issue was that the wrappers function was passed to the pure virtual's function. Defining `ShapeWrapper` this way would resolve the issue:

```
class_<ShapeWrap, boost::noncopyable>("Shape")
    .def("get_area", pure_virtual(&Shape::get_area));
```

Comment: Don't forget to accept this answer whenever you are able to do so.